# MIPS 32 ori arguments

Tags: mips32

[Here is a screenshot from qtspim:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mrzv.png)

I took it while running line by line.  Why does ori $2, $0, 5 put 4 into register 2 (v0) instead of 5?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ori $2, $0, 5` loads 5 into `$2`, that is correct.

Like most debugger, the highlighted line in qtspim is the *next* instruction to be executed. It highlights the Instruction pointed to by `IP`/`PC` (instruction pointer or process counter).

Look at the `PC` in the Register Window which points to the current (next to execute) Instruction and not the last executed.